# Oracle not able to add Default value in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle

I trying to create table in PL/SQL, the problem is the at `DEFAULT ' '`.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_TABLE AS
  strTABLE_NAME varchar2(32);
BEGIN

  strTABLE_NAME := 'Inventory';
  execute immediate 'create table '|| strTABLE_NAME ||' (STORE VARCHAR2(4) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL)';

END CREATE_TABLE ;
```

Error:

```
   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " NOT NULL)" when expecting one of the following:

  * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
  returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
  like LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between into using || bulk member
  SUBMULTISET_
  The symbol "*" was substituted for " NOT NULL)" to continue.
```

But i can add the default if i do it in sql tools. How can i add the default value in pl/sql?

```
CREATE TABLE Inventory
(
  STORE VARCHAR2(4) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes inside single quotes need to be duplicated: `default '' '' not null`

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_TABLE AS
  strTABLE_NAME varchar2(32);
BEGIN

  strTABLE_NAME := 'Inventory';
  execute immediate 'create table '|| strTABLE_NAME ||
                    ' (STORE VARCHAR2(4) DEFAULT '' '' NOT NULL)';

END CREATE_TABLE ;
```

See the manual for details and alternative ways of doing that:

[Text Literals | docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218)

Comment: or use the (in my opinion) much clearer q'[some text]'  method. That way you can just use quotes any way you like within the square brackets.

Comment: @BriteSponge: that's what I was referring to with "alternative ways"

Comment: I just find that method so useful I thought I'd mention it explicitly.